# Group MySql-Result by specific interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

With this query

```
SELECT ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(IF(DATE(o.date_purchased) = current_date, ot.value, null)), 0), 2) AS today
FROM   orders o 
JOIN   orders_total ot on ot.orders_id = o.orders_id 
WHERE  ot.class = 'ot_total'
```

I get the sales for the current day.

The column 'date_purchased' has datetime as type.

How could I count the orders for the current day or do I need a second query?
And how could I group the sales for a interval of 2 hours.

e.g.
From 00:00 - 02:00  0 sales   0 Dollars
From 02:00 - 04:00  3 sales   148,95 Dollars

and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforward and can be done very efficiently.

To get orders and sales totals for the current day, do this:

```
SELECT DATE(o.date_purchased) AS date_purchased,
       SUM(ot.value) AS sales_today,
       COUNT(*)      AS orders_today
  FROM orders AS o
  JOIN orders_total AS ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id 
 WHERE ot.class = 'ot_total'
  AND o.date_purchased >= CURRENT_DATE()
  AND o.date_purchased <  CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(ot.value)
```

Note: I don't understand your orders and orders_total tables so I am guessing a bit.

To report on a one-hour interval, you look at the above query (with the GROUP BY), and you substitute

```
DATE(ot.value) + INTERVAL HOUR(ot.value) HOUR
```

for the two places where `DATE(ot.value)` occurs.  That expression takes each timestamp and converts it to the timestamp of the most recent hour. For example, it turns `2014-01-01 11:15:22` into `2014-01-01 11:00`.  When you group by that value you get what you want.

What you want to do is report on a two-hour interval. To do that you need an expression that takes each timestamp and converts it to the timestamp of the most recent two-hour interval. For example, you need to turn `2014-01-01 11:15:22` into `2014-01-01 10:00`.   So, we need to come up with an expression to do that. Here it is. It's a bit of date-arithmetic magic.

```
DATE(ot.value) + INTERVAL (HOUR(ot.value) - HOUR(ot.value) MOD 2) HOUR
```

So your two-hour summary query looks like this.

```
SELECT DATE(o.date_purchased)  
              + INTERVAL (HOUR(o.date_purchased) 
              - HOUR(o.date_purchased) MOD 2) HOUR AS time_purchased,
       SUM(ot.value) AS sales_today,
       COUNT(*)      AS orders_today
  FROM orders AS o
  JOIN orders_total AS ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id 
 WHERE ot.class = 'ot_total'
  AND o.date_purchased >= CURRENT_DATE()
  AND o.date_purchased <  CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(o.date_purchased)  
              + INTERVAL (HOUR(o.date_purchased) 
              - HOUR(o.date_purchased) MOD 2) HOUR
```

See here for an explanation of how to do this time-interval reporting more generally. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/  This kind of SQL looks a little confusing, but it follows a straightforward code pattern.

Comment: Amazing, nearly perfect. But how can I split this result into a two hour interval, because with your query I get the total sales and total orders for the current day.

Comment: I solved it by my self, just added `GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP( o.date_purchased) DIV 7200`.

Comment: Ollie Jones, you're the best. This what I wanted to get. But how could I fill it up with the interval where are 0 Sales and 0 sales. I would like to create a bar chart with the mysql result.

Comment: @RonnyLinsener, that last requirement is tricky in MySQL. It may be time to declare victory on this question and move on.

Comment: @RonnyLinsener you can fill the gaps with PHP after you pull down the data. Let each tool do what it's good at... MySQL gets the data, PHP analyzes it!